# Window 10 lagging over 25% CPU utilization

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance

Windows 10 machine becomes very laggy at moderate CPU utilization.
Mouse moves laggy and slow, audio becomes intermittent etc...

When I check for Task Manager and Resorce Manager nothing seems wrong. Disks are idle (3%-4%), RAM is available (33%). Only CPU is at 25%-30% due to some programs like chrome or a backup software.

I think it is a low CPU usage to make the computer laggy.

I have been searching the internet for weeks. Tried everything but did not help.

Computer was running very smooth after upgrading to windows 10. After one year this issue occurred.

- Intel i7-2600K
- 16GB RAM
- 128GB SSD + 1TB HD
- GeForce GT 440 graphics